# iOS How can I parse JSON codable array with Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire

I'm trying data parsing from server with Alamofire.

(I've been trying for 2 days and it's failing.)
How can I get Json array Codable type with Alamofire?...

API :

[
{
"name": "John Doe",
"email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
"type": "Lattee",
"size": "medium"
},
{
"name": "Doe",
"email": "doe@gmail.com",
"type": "Lattee",
"size": "small"
}
]

now this is my code

in Model.swift

```
struct OrderList : Codable{
    var list : [Order]
}

enum coffeeType: String, Codable{
    case cappuccino
    case lattee
    case espressino
    case cortado
    
}
enum coffeeSize: String, Codable{
    case small
    case medium
    case large
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case small = "s"
        case medium = "m"
        case large = "l"
    }
}
struct Order: Codable {
    let email: String!
    let name : String!
    let size : coffeeSize!
    let type : coffeeType!
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case name = "Name"
        case email = "Email"
        case type  = "Type"
        case size  = "Size"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email) ?? ""
        name  = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)  ?? "Guest"
        size  = try values.decodeIfPresent(coffeeSize.self, forKey: .size) ?? .small
        type  = try values.decodeIfPresent(coffeeType.self, forKey: .type) ?? .lattee
    }
}

struct Resource<T: Codable> {
    let url       : URL
    var httpMethod: HTTPMethod = .get
}
```

I have defined it in various formats such as responseData, responseJSON, and responseCodable, but I keep getting nil or something is missing.
I know how to parse with responseJSON. but I want trying to parse by applying Codable...
it's too difficult.

---- data parsing ---

```
func load<T>(resource: Resource<T>, completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        let call = AF.request(myurl,method: resource.httpMethod, parameters: nil).responseJSON{ response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                if let JSON = response.value {
                    do{
                       let dataJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JSON, options: [])
                        let getInstanceData = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: dataJson)
                        print(getInstanceData)
                        completion(.success(getInstanceData))
                        
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(_):
                
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: I have verified that the data is parsed from the server with responseString . But I don't know how to convert that parsed data to Codable.
There are no errors, but nil values ​​are always used when the data is converted to Codable.
 ex) try JSONDecoder().decode([order].self, from: dataJson)

Comment: Would you please try to use this `response.data` instead of `response.value` ?

Comment: This cannot work. There is no dictionary containing a key `list` in the JSON. The root object is an **array**. And **never ever** declare struct members as implicit unwrapped optional, don't. Another mistake is that case sensitivity matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice on property declarations

Comment: Use `responseDecodable` rather than round tripping through `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the API returns this payload:

```
[ { "name": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@gmail.com", "type": "Lattee", "size": "medium" }, { "name": "Doe", "email": "doe@gmail.com", "type": "Lattee", "size": "small" } ]
```

these are keys that your code needs to handle:
`name`, `email`, `type`, `size`

Therefore the `Order` struct should be:

```
struct Order: Codable {
    let email: String
    let name : String
    let size : CoffeeSize
    let type : CoffeeType
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email) ?? ""
        name  = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)  ?? "Guest"
        size  = try values.decode(CoffeeSize.self, forKey: .size)
        type  = try values.decode(CoffeeType.self, forKey: .type)
    }
}

enum CoffeeType: String, Codable {
    case cappuccino
    case latte
    case espressino
    case cortado
   
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let label = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
        let lowercaseLabel = label.lowercased()
        self = CoffeeType(rawValue: lowercaseLabel) ?? .latte
    }
}

enum CoffeeSize: String, Codable {
    case small
    case medium
    case large
}
```

since there is no `list` key in the json structure therefore you don't need
struct `OrderList`. In order to get a list of orders you can simply call

```
load(resource<[Order]>) { result in
   // handle the response but now you will get the list of orders
}
```

Alternatively, I created a playground to load a json file (data.json) locally and parse it into objects you can have a look at the solution below

```
func readJsonFile(filename: String) -> String {
    guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json") else { fatalError() }
    guard let jsonData = try? String(contentsOf: fileUrl) else {
        return ""
    }
    return jsonData
}

enum CoffeeType: String, Codable {
    case cappuccino
    case latte
    case espressino
    case cortado
   
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let label = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
        let lowercaseLabel = label.lowercased()
        self = CoffeeType(rawValue: lowercaseLabel) ?? .latte
    }
}

enum CoffeeSize: String, Codable {
    case small
    case medium
    case large
}

struct Order: Codable {
    let email: String
    let name : String
    let size : CoffeeSize
    let type : CoffeeType
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email) ?? ""
        name  = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)  ?? "Guest"
        size  = try values.decode(CoffeeSize.self, forKey: .size)
        type  = try values.decode(CoffeeType.self, forKey: .type)
    }
}

func parseJsonFile() {
    let jsonStr = readJsonFile(filename: "data")
    let jsonData: Data = Data(jsonStr.utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let orders = try decoder.decode([Order].self, from: jsonData)
        orders.forEach {
            print("\($0.name)" + " - " + "\($0.type.rawValue)" + " - " + "\($0.size.rawValue)")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

parseJsonFile()
```

Result:

```
John Doe - latte - medium
Doe - latte - small
```

Comment: Thanks for detail answer. I learn new implement CodingKeys and etc  from your answer.
However, (JSONDecodable().decode(_:from:) logic has still not convert Codable [Order] arrays ..
"
https://github.com/SHcommit/LearnMoreSwiftInUdemy/issues/5
"
This is my current issue

Comment: it already applied, you were able to print out the `type`, `name`. The email value is missing because you haven't copied exact all my codable objects for example: email is no longer optional property of Order object

Comment: OH wow wow.... Thanks ... very very successful. What Was the problem with my code?? An incorrect Model's Codable definition?. From someone else's answer above, I found that case sensitivity and implicitly unwrapped optionals are bad implementations. I'd like to know more about the problem with my code.

Comment: I tried to explain more details, but the limit of this comment so please look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73597402/3138033

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is case-sensitive properties.
If the API returns these keys `Name`, `Type`, `Email`, `Size`, `Type` then the Codable object should have the coding Keys to handle keys from API

```
struct Order: Codable { 
  let email: String 
  let name : String 
  let size : CoffeeSize 
  let type : CoffeeType 

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{ 
     case name = "Name" 
     case email = "Email" 
     case type = "Type" 
     case size = "Size" 
    }
}
```

In terms of unwrapping properties, it will depend on the contract between your code and API. If you're pretty sure API will always return `size`,`type`, `name` but `email` is nullable. Then you should use the method `decodeIfPresent` allows the value of the parsing key is nullable
If you're certain about `name`, the value is always not null, then you can use `decode` normally

and your Order struct will become

```
struct Order: Codable { 
  let email: String? 
  let name : String 
  let size : CoffeeSize 
  let type : CoffeeType 

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{ 
     case name = "Name" 
     case email = "Email" 
     case type = "Type" 
     case size = "Size" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ,,, It's a little difficult, but you explained it well, so I understood it well. Thank you for your kind and detailed information.

I need to study more about decode. Thank you very much.

Have a good weekend :)